# Use Lodash to transform this nested json data

Tags: javascript, json, nested, underscore.js, lodash

I'm new to lodash. I have this kind of json data. I already have 90-120 lines of code that parses it, does some calculation to it, and creates new json. It's becoming a nightmare.

I would like to ask help on how I can transform this json using lodash's methods.

http://pastebin.com/BjBLwJDA

```
[
    {
        "dates": [
            {
                "datetime": "2014-08-26",
                "deviceModels": [
                    {
                        "deviceModel": "Canon450MX",
                        "devices": [
                            {
                                "deviceModel": "Canon450MX",
                                "inchesPrinted": 10,
                                "serialNum" : "111"
                            },
                            {
                                "deviceModel": "Canon450MX",
                                "inchesPrinted": 10,
                                "serialNum" : "222"
                            },
                            {
                                "deviceModel": "Canon450MX",
                                "inchesPrinted": 10,
                                "serialNum" : "333"
                            }
                        ]
                    },
                    {
                        "deviceModel": "HPDeskjet",
                        "devices": [
                            {
                                "deviceModel": "HPDeskjet",
                                "inchesPrinted": 20,
                                "serialNum" : "444"
                            },
                            {
                                "deviceModel": "HPDeskjet",
                                "inchesPrinted": 20,
                                "serialNum" : "555"
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "datetime": "2014-08-27",
                "deviceModels": [
                    {
                        "deviceModel": "Canon450MX",
                        "devices": [
                            {
                                "deviceModel": "Canon450MX",
                                "inchesPrinted": 5,
                                "serialNum" : "111"
                            },
                            {
                                "deviceModel": "Canon450MX",
                                "inchesPrinted": 25,
                                "serialNum" : "222"
                            },
                            {
                                "deviceModel": "Canon450MX",
                                "inchesPrinted": 15,
                                "serialNum" : "333"
                            }
                        ]
                    },
                    {
                        "deviceModel": "HPDeskjet",
                        "devices": [
                            {
                                "deviceModel": "HPDeskjet",
                                "inchesPrinted": 10,
                                "serialNum" : "444"
                            },
                            {
                                "deviceModel": "gx420d",
                                "inchesPrinted": 20,
                                "serialNum" : "555"
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

I would like the new output json to be like this:

```
[
    { date : 2014-08-26, deviceModel : 'Canon450MX', totalInchesPrinted : 30 },
    { date : 2014-08-26, deviceModel : 'HPDeskJet', totalInchesPrinted : 40 },
    { date : 2014-08-27, deviceModel : 'Canon450MX', totalInchesPrinted : 45 },
    { date : 2014-08-27, deviceModel : 'HPDeskJet', totalInchesPrinted : 30 }
]
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This should transform the data into the required form:

```
    var sumInchesPrinted = function(total, device){
        return total + device.inchesPrinted
    }

    var transformDeviceModels = function(dates){
        return _.map(dates.deviceModels, function(deviceModel){
            return {
                date: dates.datetime,
                deviceModel: deviceModel.deviceModel,
                totalInchesPrinted: _.reduce(deviceModel.devices, sumInchesPrinted, 0)
            }
        });
    };

    var data = _.chain(list[0].dates)
        .map(transformDeviceModels)
        .flatten()
        .value();
```

Comment: I tried it and WOW, it worked!!! It's very clean compared to my own native for nested messy loops, HAHAHA! Thank you so much!

Btw, I tried clicking the up arrow to vote it up. I got an error saying I need 15 reputation.

Comment: Gruff Bunny, is there any Lodash book that you can recommend or a url that has great tutorial other than the API documentation?

Comment: There's a pretty good book called 'Functional Javascript' (Michael Fogus) which uses the underscore library, but it's not a tutorial on underscore. Apart from that I would just play with one function at a time from the library until you're comfortable with how it works. A good understanding of map and reduce would benefit you greatly as these programming constructs crop up very often in the real world.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the advice! I'll follow everything you said. :)

Comment: Btw, I'm trying to figure out how the params in sumInchesPrinted gets populated even if we are only calling it like this

`totalInchesPrinted: _.reduce(deviceModel.devices, sumInchesPrinted, 0)
`

http://imgur.com/oVOfVM8

Comment: Reduce reduces a collection to a single value. Here we want to calculate the sum of the total inches printed for each device. Reduce works by applying a function to each item in a collection and passing the returned value to the function during the next iteration. The first time the function is called we are passing in zero as the initial value.

Comment: I understand reduce now :)

Comment: Thanks for using reduce, it's a good demonstration that you can easily change the calculation of whatever values you're looking at, without having to change too much code (and you get to do it in isolation). I also dig the chaining, well done!